# How to write a function that takes an Array of strings as an argument and prints the first letter of each element out (one per line)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, charat, for-of-loop

I am working on my first javascript assignment and we have been asked to "Write a function that takes an Array of strings as an argument and prints the first letter of each element out (one per line)" however **we must use a FOR OF loop, function, and charAt()** the output should be
H
W
T
I
M
S each letter on its own line
I am struggling because  I only know how to complete the task by using the toString.charAt method but that is not what the assignment asked for. I also am not sure if the for of loop goes in the function or the function goes in the loop. Just started JS last week very confused. Please help.

```
let arr = (["Hello", "World", "This", "Is", "My", "String"]);
//  required for of
for (let element of arr) {
    console.log(element.toString())
}
 



// required function
let myFunction = (element) => element.charAt(0);

 myFunction(arr)
 

// required charAt
var str = new String( "This is string" );

        
         console.log( arr.toString().charAt(0));
         console.log(  arr.toString().charAt(6));
         console.log(  arr.toString().charAt(12));
         console.log(  arr.toString().charAt(17));
         console.log(  arr.toString().charAt(20));
         console.log( arr.toString().charAt(23));
```

Comment: `console.log(myFunction(element))`

Answer (score 0):

See below four examples, the first one is your answer, they are loops.

```js
let arr = (["Hello", "World", "This", "Is", "My", "String"]);

let myFunction = element => console.log(element.charAt(0));

console.log('\nfor of mode');
for (const iterator of arr) {
    myFunction(iterator);
}

console.log('\nfor each mode');
arr.forEach(element => {
    myFunction(element);
});

console.log('\nfor each mode2');
arr.forEach( el => myFunction(el) );

console.log('\nfor mode');
for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    const element = arr[index];
    myFunction(element);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression on each loop:

> ```
> // word is a string from the array of strings
> word.toString().charAt(0)+'\n'
> ```

**Details are commented in example below**

```js
let hwtims = ["Hello", "World", "This", "Is", "My", "String"];
/*
Declare new string outside of loop: let char = ''
On each loop add to char: +=
Get the first character of each
word: .toString().charAt(0)
Add a newline: +'\n'
*/
const firstChar = array => {
  let char = '';
  for (let word of array) {
    char += word.toString().charAt(0) + '\n';
  }
  return char;
};

console.log(firstChar(hwtims));
```